# find images and delete images in excel using openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, image, openpyxl

I Have an excel in which im doing multiple tasks using openpyxl like reading and modifying data in cells. there is an image and a shape present in the same excel and im trying to have it deleted/removed but i cannot find any modules to achieve it. i can add an image but could'nt delete. Is there any possible way of removing an image from openpyxl

openpyxl.reader.drawings.find_images() tried using this module but not sure about its implementation

```
for image in sheet._images:
    print(image)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
wb['worksheet']._images
```

The above gives you a list of the images as you mentioned above, then you can `del` the index of the image you would like to delete.

```
del wb['worksheet']._images [1]
```

[1] being a sample index of an image to delete, and as always, don't forget to save.

```
wb.save('wb.xlsx')
```

The image should then be removed.

PS- This was my first SO answer so feel free to give me some pointers!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, I could delete all images like this.

```
sheet._images = []
```

But in my case I had to delete all png files, so I solved like this.

```
images = []
for sheet in wb:     
    for image in sheet._images:
        if image.path[-3:] !="png":
            images.append(image)
            
    sheet._images =   images
```